# How to solve $(x^2 - 11x + 29)^{(6x^2 + x - 2)}=1$?

Tags: polynomials, quadratics

This question comes from PURE MATHEMATICS 1 for As and A levels. This question is part of exercise 1 and it has 5 Answers : $1/2, - 2/3, 4, 6 $ and $7$ . The first 2 values $1/2$ and $- 
2/3 $ I am able to find but the rest I can't. I get this first 2 values by make 1 to $(x^2 - 11x + 29)^0$ and this solving by transposition as base of power are same so they get cancelled and make it $(6x^2 + x - 2)=0.$

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  In order for the MathJax commands to take effect, you must surround them with `$` signs.

Comment: Ohm, how about $x^2-11x+29 = 1$ ? Gives you two more ;)

Comment: The signs are now wrong on the first two: should be 1/2 and -2/3

Comment: Thanks for mentioning it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By inspection, $$a^b=1 \Rightarrow a=1\textrm{ or }b=0 \textrm{ or } a=-1 \textrm{ if } b \textrm{ is even}$$

So we can just solve three different cases.

Case 1:  $a=1$.
\begin{align}x^2-11x+29&=1\\
x^2-11x+28&=0\\
(x-4)(x-7)&=0\\
x_1&=4\\
x_2&=7\end{align}

Case 2:  $b=0$.
\begin{align}
6x^2+x-2&=0\\
(3x+2)(2x-1)&=0\\
x_3&=-\frac23\\
x_4&=\frac12
\end{align}

Case 3:  $a=-1$ and $b$ is even.
\begin{align}
x^2-11x+29&=-1\\
x^2-11x+30&=0\\
(x-5)(x-6)&=0\\
x_5&=5 &\textrm{(inadmissible)}\\
x_6&=6
\end{align}

The possible answers are therefore $\boxed{x=-\frac23,\frac12,4,6,7}$.

Comment: A nice YouTube video by MindYourDecisions has a [similar question](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C7A3uFC76G0).

Answer (score 3):

Don't get tricked.

If $b\ne 0$ and $b \ne \pm 1$ then $b^w = 1$ if and only if $w=0$.

And if $b=1$ then $b^w =1$ no matter what $w$ equals.

And if $b =-1$ then $b^w=1$ if $w$ is even integer or $w$ is a rational number where, in lowest terms, the numerator is even. (we can call that an "even rational".)

And if $b=0$ then $b^w=1$ is impossible.  ($0^0$ is undefined.)

So if $b = x^2 -11x + 29$ and if $w = 6x^2+ x-2$ then

$b^w = 1$ if

1) $b= x^2 -11x + 29 =1$

Or if

2) $w= 6x^2+ x-2=0$ and $b=x^2 -11x + 29\ne 0$.

of if

3) $b=x^2-11x + 29 =-1$ and $w=  6x^2+ x-2$ is an "even rational".

So just solve those.

=====

1) $x^2 -11x + 29 =1\implies x^2 -11x + 28 =0 \implies x =\frac {11\pm\sqrt {11^2 -4*28}}2=\frac {11\pm \sqrt{9}}2 = \frac {11-3}2 = 4,7$.

So $x =4$ or $x = 7$ are solutions.

$(4^2 - 11*4+29)^{6*4^2 +4 -2} = 1^{98} = 1$ and $(7^2 -11*7 + 29)^{6*7^2+ 7 -2} = 1^{299} = 1$.

2) $6x^2 +x -2 =0 \implies x=\frac {-1\pm\sqrt{1-4*(-2)*6}}{2*6} = \frac {-1\pm \sqrt {49}}{12} = \frac {-1\pm 7}12 = \frac 12$ or $-\frac 23$

If $x = \frac 12;-\frac 23$ then $x^2 -11x + 29\ne 0$ so these are fine.  We have:

$(x^2 -11x + 29)^{6x^2 +x -2}=(x^2-11x+29)^0 = 1$.

3)$x^2 -11x + 29 =-1\implies x^2 -11x + 30 =0\implies x=\frac {11\pm \sqrt{11^2 - 4*30}}{2}=\frac {11\pm 1}2= 5,6$ but this is impossible as $11^2 - 4*30 = -9$.

But we need $6x^2 +x -2$ to be even.  $6*25+ 5-2$ is odd, but $6*36+6-2$ is even.

So $x = 6$ is a solution.

$(6^2 -11*6 + 29)^{6*36+6-2} = (-1)^{220} = 1$.

.... so solutions are $x =\frac 12; -\frac 23, 4,7, 6$.

Comment: What about $(-1)^2=1$?

Comment: Yeah.... I realized that and added that.

Comment: Dang... I have to *stop* making arithmetic errors.  $121 - 112 \ne -1$ and $121 - 4*30 \ne -9$.  *!sheesh!*

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Taking the logarithm on both sides we get
$$(6x^2+x-2)\ln(x^2-11x+29)=0$$ so
$$6x^2+x-2=0$$ or $$x^2-11x+29=1$$

Comment: "logarithm on both sides" Assuming we can.  We can't take the ln if $x^2 -11x+29 \le 0$.

Comment: It is $$x^2-11x+29>0$$ for all real $x$

Comment: should point that out though, shouldn't you.

Comment: Oh, it is $$29-\frac{121}{4}=\frac{116-121}{4}<0$$

Comment: The constant would have to be greater than $5.5^2=30.25$ to always be positive.

Comment: So we can do the logarithm thing only for $$x<\frac{1}{2}(11-\sqrt{5})$$ or $$x>\frac{1}{2}(11+\sqrt{5})$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: few possibilities:

- $a^{0}=1$ where $a\ne 0$
- $1^{p}=1$, $\forall p\in \mathbb{R}$
- $(-1)^{2n}=1$ where $n\in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Last case should be $(-1)^{\frac pq}$ with $p\in 2\mathbb Z, q\in 2\mathbb N+1$ and $\gcd(p,q)=1$.

Comment: @zwim We seldom define fractional index from negative base.  The principal value is usually in complex.  See the *Wolfram Alpha* output for $(-1)^{2/3}$ [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28-1%29%5E%282%2F3%29).

Comment: I think I know... https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3356544/is-12-16-a-real-number/3356598#3356598

Comment: This is not covered in As or A Lvl maths

Answer (score 0):

It's simple

This equation is true when either $x^2 -11x+29=1$ or $6x^2+x-2 =0$ or $x^2-11x+29=-1 \ \  and  \ \ 6x^2+x-2= even$ because $1^k=1$ and $n^0=1$ and $(-1)^{even}=0$

Solve the equations

You have solved second equation so I'll leave that

For the first  you will get $$x^2 -11x+28=0$$

$$(x-7)(x-4)=0$$

Solution is$ x=4,7 $as you desired

For third equation

$x^2-11x+30=0\ \ and \ \ 6x^2+x-2= even$

We get

$$x=5,6 \ \ and \ \ 6x^2+x-2=even$$

Plug in each value

For $x=5 6x^2+x-2=153$ which is odd

But for $x=6 6x^2+x-2= 220$ which is even

So x=6 is also a solution

This method is consistent with the As and A Lvl maths