# Representing $(\sin\pi t)$with Euler's formula

Tags: complex-numbers, signal-processing

So I know how to represent $\sin(kw_{0}t)$ using Euler's formula as $\frac{1}{2j}(e^{jkw_0t} - e^{-jkw_0t})$, but when I try to represent $sin(\pi t)$ using the same method I get:
\begin{align*}
\sin(\pi t) = \frac{1}{2j}(e^{j \pi t} + e^{-j \pi t})
\end{align*}
My question is why can't I write $e^{j \pi t}$ as $(e^{j\pi})^t = (-1)^{t}$ and get $0$ for every $t$?

Comment: What does $(-1)^t$ mean for non-integer $t$?

Comment: You can have a look at my post here [is (-1)^2.16 a real number](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3356598/399263) I tried to explain the significance of $(-1)^t$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with complex number you have that $e^{i\pi t} \neq (e^{i\pi})^t$ because the complex logarithm is a multi-valued function, you can see it on Wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Exponentiation).