# What is the result of a fractional power of a squared quantity?

Tags: real-analysis

Simple question:  Is the following assertion valid?

$$
(x^2)^{\frac{n}{2}} = |x|^n
$$
for $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and integer $n>0$.  Whether yes or no, please help me understand why or why not.

Comment: $(x^2)^{\frac{n}{2}} = |x^2|^{\frac{n}{2}} = |x|^{2\frac{n}{2}} = |x|^n$

Comment: Thank you @Klaus, you clearly support the assertion!

Comment: @Klaus.  Is it the round brackets that validate it?

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: @Klaus Perhaps the following is a more precise way of illustrating the exact point of the question.  Suppose $x=-1$ and $n=1$.  Now $x^{2\times\frac{1}{2}}=x^{1}=-1$ whereas the assertion in the question results in $|x|^1=1$.

Comment: You are using $(x^a)^b = x^{ab}$ for negative numbers, which is not allowed. So yes, the brackets make sure you evaluate $x^a$ first and then continue.

Comment: That's clear, much appreciated.

Comment: This is correct. For further understanding you can also look at my answer here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3356598/399263 which explains how to deal with negative $x$

Comment: Let n=1.  Then you have $\sqrt{x^2}=\pm x$, ignoring convention of taking only positive solution.

Comment: @Klaus Your engagement is appreciated.  The way this topic is described in Wikipedia (not that what is there is guaranteed to be correct) appears to read that $(x^a)^b = x^{ab}$ is permissible even for negative $x$ when $a$, $b$ are integers, but that $x^r$ is defined only for positive $x$ when $r$ is rational.  What are your views?

Comment: @zwim, your views as well?

Comment: @RickyBoy Yes, if $a$ and $b$ are integers, then $(x^a)^b = x^{ab}$ is fine even for negative $x$. The difference between integer powers and non-integer powers is that integer powers are defined via multiplication while non-integer powers are defined either by roots (e.g. $\sqrt{\cdot}$ is power $\frac{1}{2}$) or via the exponential function. Multiplication of negative numbers is fine, taking roots of negative numbers can be a problem if you are not careful.

Comment: @Klaus. OK thanks for that.  But perhaps you can clarify for me...  In my question, $n$ is integer.  You have above advised that my example for $n=1$ is not allowed for $x=-1$.  So I am a bit confused.  It is leading me to believe that it is only because of the brackets surrounding $(x^2)$ in the question that is allowing us to write $x^2=|x|^2$ so we may assert $(x^2)^{\frac{n}{2}} = |x|^n > 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.  Would you agree with that?

Comment: @RickyBoy $n = 1$ is an integer, but $\frac{n}{2} = \frac{1}{2}$ is not. $x^2 = |x|^2$ is true for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Klaus.  You are indeed correct and of course it is obvious!  There is a lot to be said for enlisting the help of someone who hasn't stared at a problem for too long.  Haha.  Again, your engagement is very much appreciated.  Thank you.  (I cannot "accept' the answer because it is in a comment, but let it be known this is the accepted answer, with thanks.)